# is the system corect after deleting swap and merging with root?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

i have deleted the swap partition and merged with root , now this is how the Gparted looks like:

[image: image of Gparted after deleting swap and merging with root]

so is everything correct because i see 2 partitions apart from boot and i suspect it should be the same 1 partition since my SSD capacity is 250 GB.

Comment: Why did you remove swap? Unless you've moved it to a HDD.

Comment: to optimize my SSD.

Comment: Not having swap space is probably worse than losing a year of life or two of your SSD of the 15 or so it has even under extreme use.

Comment: @David Foerster : so how much swap do you suggest under no hibernation?

Comment: See [How to decide on Swap size](/q/62073/175814).

Comment: General rule is 1-1.5x RAM size (for RAM sizes 16G or less). For RAM > 16G, make it 8-16G, unless you hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks correct.

You have a /boot partition (sda1), then an extended partition (sda2) that contains a partition with a logical volume (sda5). This is supposed to contain your / (root) and other filssystems.

If you have removed the swap entry from /etc/fstab it should boot fine.

Comment: but sda2 and sda5 are the same. shouldn't it show as 1 partition?

Comment: sda2 is an extended partition that contains sda5 as a logical partition. Originally partitioning only supported 4 primary partitions, To be able to have more than 4 partitions, extended partitions was created, that can contain more logical partitons.